# Digikam is freezing after an external USB drive change from 8TB to 16TB

Tags: external-hard-drive, digikam

I am running Lubuntu 20.04LTS and I have [Digikam](https://www.digikam.org) (6.4.0) scanning my external hard drive `/media/my/8/TB/drive/images` but just recently upgraded to a 16TB drive, so the path is now `/media/my/16/TB/drive/images`.

On the file manager, this is all fine, but when I try to scan for new images Digikam freezes completely.

I believe that's because it still expects ../8 to be there. Just a guess.

Normally when I start Digikam, it will show a little progress bar as it peeks at the "images" directory to see if there are any new files… that's not happening now. It just loads and is immediately ready.  So I think it just is looking at the now-not-there drive and saying "Nothing new."

My question is whether I will be completely erasing or losing my info if I use the "Settings" and remove the "images" drive from Digikam and then add a new one.  Will this cause a massive headache of Digikam thinking I've added an entirely new set of files?  Will it be days and days of it loading all the metadata from these files?

I am guessing I could mount the 16TB drive in the old 8TB drive location, but ideally, I'd just like to tell Digikam "Hey, that location has moved to here now.  Look here from now on."

Can I do that? Anyone know?  Thank you in advance for helpful suggestions.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas  As written above, Lubuntu 20.04LTS.  :-)

Comment: I tried something I thought was a grand idea, which was to make a symlink from the new drive to the old location.  But that didn't work either.  For a brief moment the "Finding new media" bar pops up and then it vanishes.  I think it's just not finding the new media somehow.

Comment: Can you run it through `strace` and see what it is up to?

Comment: Haven't used strace before, so is there something specific I should be typing to get the best info?  And more, I'm just wondering if I'll lose data by switching the directory in the Settings.  If I won't, I think the easy solution will just be to switch to that new location and problem solved.  But thank you for the suggestion.  I'll run strace tomorrow and see what it comes up with.

Comment: `strace` is the system call tracer for Linux.  You just launch whatever it is with the strace command in front of it.  If it's a GUI app, then you will need to open a terminal to spawn it.  It will give you way WAY more information than you ever wanted but has helped me countless time when figuring out what isn't working on a Linux system.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, @SeñorCMasMas I ran strace and now need to know what to look for.  Also, since there's so much info, am I able to dump this to a text file or log?  The terminal scrolls up so vastly that I can't see the entire data output.

Comment: [Here are some nice methods](https://superuser.com/questions/561696/redirect-strace-to-file).  Yes, there is a f-ton of information.. and it doesn't always point you to the problem.. but has saved my butt more than once.

Comment: Thanks, @SeñorCMasMas -- Just curious, do you have experience in digikam or just mainly suggesting I use strace?  I'm ideally hoping for answers as to how to fix this.  Any ideas?